# "No route maatches [GET] " error in rspec integration test for rails 3.2.12

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

What the integration test does is to open a show purchasing page and click `Approve` on the purchasing page. Here is the rspec case:

```
it "should display the approve page" do
      proj = FactoryGirl.create(:project)
      pur = FactoryGirl.create(:purchasing, :project_id => proj.id)
      visit project_purchasing_path(proj, pur)
      response.should have_selector("a", :href => approve_project_purchasing_path(proj, pur), :content => "Approve")
      click_link 'Approve'
end
```

The last line `click_link 'Approve'` causes the error below even though the `response` just verifies that there is `'Approve'` link on the page:

```
ActionController::RoutingError:←[0m
           ←[31mNo route matches [GET] "/projects/1/purchasings/1/approve"
```

In output of `rake routes` there is a path approve_project_purchasing_path:

```
 approve_project_purchasing PUT    /projects/:project_id/purchasings/:id/approve(.:format)
```

The code execution has no error at all when clicking `'Approve'`.

What's wrong in our rspec code? Thanks for the help.

UPDATE: 
here is the `link_to` for `Approve`:

```
<%= link_to 'Approve', approve_project_purchasing_path(@project, @purchasing), :method => :put, :id => 'purchasing_need_approve', :confirm => 'Approve' + @purchasing.prod_name + '?' %>
```

Comment: Are you using javascript to submit the form?  If so, you'll need a javascript-enabled integration test driver to simulate that.  The test is generating a GET whereas you've only defined a PUT.  Seems like a legitimate problem.

Comment: What's the javascript-enabled integration test driver? Approve uses link_to with :confirm which pops up a alert asking if you want to approve. Is it the javascript that you mentioned?

Comment: Let me back up slightly.  Are you using capybara?  If so, you'll want to use selenium or install capybara_webkit for the JS stuff (that's what I meant re: JS-enabled integration test driver).  I think you need to do this as a proper form or use a button instead of a link_to, since the driver is ignoring your :method => :put stuff.

Comment: group :development, :test do  
  gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.0.0"
  gem 'webrat', ">= 0.7.2"
  gem 'factory_girl_rails' #, '~> 3.0'
end                         .Here is the gemfile.

Comment: Approve is a custom action to assign a few values, with no form.

Comment: You might consider trying capybara.  It may be a limitation of webrate - I'm not really sure.  Ultimately webrat is giving you a GET where you expect a PUT, so your options are to fix/ditch webrat or accept a GET.  :)

Comment: @Dave S, changed link_to to button_to and click_link to click_button. The click_button 'Approve' passed. Not quite understand the difference between capybara and webrate. thanks for the help.